# Why did Logan turn back to that specific time in the future

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

So Kitty uses her power to send Logan back to the past to change it in [*X-Men: Days of Future Past*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/).
It all works 'fine' but when Logan finishes his job and saves the future, what makes him appear right on that moment with Charles X., where Charles says: "You are back ..." (after announcing that Logan is a history teacher).

If Logan finished the job in the last why did he come to that specific time?
Why didn't he just 'disappear' since what happened in the future never happened.

Also why doesn't Logan remember anything after 1973? As he changed everything, in 1973 he should have had a normal life, and according to Charles he would become a history teacher.
How come he doesn't remember that?

Logan's mind got in the mind of the 1973 Logan, but only for a few days. So if he changed the past, Kitty wouldn't have used her power on Logan, she probably wouldn't even knew it since there should be no 'X-men - Team' since the world should be in peace.

So technically Logan's mind would be stuck in 1973?

Or what really happened here?

Comment: [Probable duplicate](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19829/which-wolverine-existed-during-the-time-gap)

Comment: @TylerShads ,the issue that you linked is a question about his existance, ofcourse he existed. I just wanted to know why he came to that certain point back in the future and didn't stay stuck in the past as Kitty shouldn't have used her powers or should it?

Comment: Good Question, in my opinion.  I haven't even seen the movie yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Logan we see at the end is has the same consciousness of the Logan from 2023-D (Dystopian Future).

In 1973, a timeline split occurs that creates 2 separate futures, one that leads into the Dystopian [D] future, and another that leads into what is shown at the end of the movie (we'll call it "peaceful [P]" future), 2023-P.

In 2023-P, Logan is a history teacher at Xavier's school, far as we know he was still involved in everything he was involved in upto 1973, both world wars, American civil war, etc.  However, once 2023-D Logan completes his mission, **his consciousness is sent back to that exact moment in time that it would be in 2023-D**, but seeing as that future no longer exists in the "main" timeline (Isn't time travel fun?!?!?!?!?!) he "overrides" 2023-P Logan as there is now nowhere for his consciousness to go.  Similar to how he was "overriding" 1973 Logan.

This is why Xavier, despite obviously having Logan as a teacher at his school for however long it has been in this timeline, is surprised to see him and notices that this is the same Logan he met in 1973 at the split, that came back to "save the future".

It is also why Logan doesn't know what has happened in the gap between 1973 - 2023-P because he only has his memories from 1973 - 2023-D, which includes X-Men Origins: Wolverine, meaning in this timeline we can assume this movie *has not happened* (as far as we know).

Comment: Quote: his consciousness is sent back to that exact moment in time that it would be in 2023-D,

So if Kitty used her power at 2023-D let's say 05/05 11.22AM
And Logan finishes his job, he would be sent back to 2023-D 05/05 11.22AM, but the old Logan, that makes sense yea thanks.

Comment: @Decypher Exactly.  I believe they explained, and it makes sense, that Logan's actions in 1973 are *not* reflected in realtime in 2023-D.  So he could've been under Kitty's power for only a couple hours, lets assume, instead of the ~week the events of 1973 seem to take place over.

Comment: That's kinda creepy. This means that Logan from "peaceful" time lived his life up until the point when "dystopian" Logan overridden his mind. Meaning that "peaceful" Logan just ceased to exist